# Generation of Dependency matrix

Tags: java, matrix

My functional dependency looks like :

```
 A->BD,
 C->D, 
EF->B,
 D->CE
```

I want to generate matrix displayed below-

```
   | A | B | C | D | E | F
--------------------------
A  | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
C  | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0
EF | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2
D  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0
```

I have tried hard but didn't get any solutions, looking forward to get any solutions.

Comment: So what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Attempted solution is important also to clarify how you take input, and how you expect output to happen. A line of code speaks more than several paragraphs of explanation.

Comment: Either your input is not full, or you need to say more about logic you must use to generate such output.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm since we don't see what format the input is in this is a bit harder but a general approach would be :

1. Create an array for every possible lefthandside of the dependencies you have with the size of the amount of possible different letters (in your example 6).
2. Run through the arrays setting all the "self-entries" (where the entry is a letter from your arrayname) to `2`.
3. For each dependency go to the corresponding array and set all the entries that correspond to the righthandside of the dependency to `1`.

You end up with an array for each dependency which you can then either print into the matrix you want or do some other calculations with.

If you need more help or some code samples let me know.